# Join 2D string array more elegantly

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, formatting

I have a list of argument and value pairs, that I want to join into the format

`-arg0=val0 -arg1=val1 ... -argN=valN`

The following code works but it feels a bit clumsy and I suspect it can be written in a more elegant way, without an explicit loop.

[Run on dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nctBvy)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var argumentValueList = new string[,]
        {
            {"foo", "bar"},
            {"fop", "bas"},
            {"foq", "bat"}
        };
        
        var parameterList = new List<string>();
        
        for (int i=0;i < argumentValueList.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            parameterList.Add($"-{argumentValueList[i, 0]}={argumentValueList[i, 1]}");
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" " ,parameterList));
    }
}
```

Expected Output:

`-foo=bar -fop=bas -foq=bat`

**Question: Is there a way to write this without an explicit loop, potentially as a one-liner?**

Comment: You cannot change array sizes in c#.  Use a list instead.  Try :             List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> argumentValueList = new List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>()
           {
             new KeyValuePair<string,string>("foo", "bar"),
             new KeyValuePair<string,string>("fop", "bas"),
             new KeyValuePair<string,string>("foq", "bat")
           };

Comment: @jdweng I don't see how that has any relevance to my question. Furthermore, there's no need to change the array size nor is it referenced anywhere explicitely.

Comment: You can also use a dictionary :             Dictionary<string,string> argumentValueList = new Dictionary<string,string>()
           { {"foo", "bar"}, {"fop", "bas"}, {"foq", "bat"}};

Comment: You are saying that ADD doesn't change the size of an array?

Comment: jdweng I'm calling Add on a List, not on an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest *changing* collection into `Dictionary<string, string>` where `Key` is command line key and `Value` is corresponding value.  Then you can easily query this dictionary with a help of *Linq*:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var argumentValueList = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"foo", "bar"},
            {"fop", "bas"},
            {"foq", "bat"},
        };
        
        var commandLine = string.Join(" ", argumentValueList
          .Select(pair => $"-{pair.Key}={pair.Value}")); 
        
        Console.WriteLine(commandLine);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I also came up with, with the help of jdweng's comment and Smartis' answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me more like Code-Golf.

#### Using `System.Linq;`

1. `Enumerable.Range()` to generate a sequence of integers from 0 to the length of the first dimension of the two-dimensional array
2. `Select()` to transform each integer into a formatted string using string interpolation
3. `Aggregate()` to concatenate all the formatted strings into a single string, separated by spaces

```cs
string result = Enumerable.Range(0, argumentValueList.GetLength(0))
    .Select(i => $"-{argumentValueList[i, 0]}={argumentValueList[i, 1]}")
    .Aggregate((a, b) => $"{a} {b}");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it a bit more elegant by using a `foreach` loop. That would look like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var argumentValueList = new[,]
        {
            {"foo", "bar"},
            {"fop", "bas"},
            {"foq", "bat"}
        };

        var parameterList = new List<string>();

        foreach (var (arg, value) in argumentValueList)
        {
            parameterList.Add($"-{arg}={value}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", parameterList));
    }
```

I don't think converting the logic in this method into a one liner is a very good idea when readability is taken into account, although that is a preference thing.

Comment: Ah, very nice use of `(arg, value)`, that still is kinda new to me.

Comment: It's called tuple deconstruction, more info here in docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples

Answer (score 0):

This is best one line I could come up with. Similar to Smartis soultion.

```
string.Join(" ", Enumerable.Range(0, argumentValueList.GetLength(0)).Select(x => "-" + argumentValueList[x, 0] + "=" + argumentValueList[x, 1]))
```